# PostGIS 3.3, ST_DWithin Query - "lwgeom_distance_spheroid returned negative!" by changing third arg? Postgres 11, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, st-dwithin

The unexpected error:

`lwgeom_distance_spheroid returned negative!`

By making a tiny change in the third argument (distance) to ST_DWithin, we get an error in one version but not another. In other words, by changing the distance by a tiny fraction: 3754219.5 -> 3754219.6 we get the error.

This distance where it starts failing is different for different POINTs.

Additionally, geometry or geography makes no difference, it only changes the value where the distance error occurs.

It does not happen on Ubuntu 16.04, Postgres 11, PostGIS 2.5.

I've tried to isolate it here:

FAILING ON Ubuntu 20.04 PostGIS 3.3:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
psql (11.19 (Ubuntu 11.19-1.pgdg20.04+1))
```

```
# SELECT VERSION();
                                                               version                                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.19 (Ubuntu 11.19-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

# SELECT postgis_full_version();
                                                                        postgis_full_version                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="3.3.2 4975da8" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2" PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
(1 row)

# SELECT PostGIS_Liblwgeom_Version();
 postgis_liblwgeom_version 
---------------------------
 3.3.2 4975da8
(1 row)

# SELECT ST_DWithin('SRID=4326;POINT(-74.8456 40.1752)','SRID=4326;POINT(-118.493 34.0172)', 3754219.5, true) as is_within;
 is_within 
-----------
 f
(1 row)

# SELECT ST_DWithin('SRID=4326;POINT(-74.8456 40.1752)','SRID=4326;POINT(-118.493 34.0172)', 3754219.6, true) as is_within;
ERROR:  lwgeom_distance_spheroid returned negative!
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_dwithin" statement 1

# 
SUCCESSFUL ON Ubuntu 16.04 PostGIS 2.5:

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
sql (12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg16.04+1), server 11.6 (Ubuntu 11.6-1.pgdg16.04+1))
You are now connected to database "mydatabasewithpostgisinit" as user "postgres".
=# SELECT VERSION();
                                                                   version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.6 (Ubuntu 11.6-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)

=# SELECT postgis_full_version();
                                                                                                   postgis_full_version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="2.5.3 r17699" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER
(1 row)

=# SELECT PostGIS_Liblwgeom_Version();
 postgis_liblwgeom_version
---------------------------
 2.5.3 r17699
(1 row)

=# SELECT ST_DWithin('SRID=4326;POINT(-74.8456 40.1752)','SRID=4326;POINT(-118.493 34.0172)', 3754219.5, true) as is_within;
 is_within
-----------
 f
(1 row)

=# SELECT ST_DWithin('SRID=4326;POINT(-74.8456 40.1752)','SRID=4326;POINT(-118.493 34.0172)', 3754219.6, true) as is_within;
 is_within
-----------
 f
(1 row)

# SELECT ST_DWithin('SRID=4326;POINT(-74.8456 40.1752)','SRID=4326;POINT(-118.493 34.0172)', 111113754219.6, true) as is_within;
 is_within 
-----------
 t
```

You can see, for a huge distance, in the working version, it still doesn't fail on 2.5.

Is this a bug? Or has something changed? I haven't been able to find any explanation for it.

Comment: To narrow your problem, query with distance 3754219.6 works also with version "POSTGIS="3.1.2 3.1.2"

Comment: of course it is a bug... throwing an error on valid inputs is not expected. You can report it [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/report)  (PS: it works fine under 3.2.1)

Comment: The bug posted here:  https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5355 There is a comment that it could be the "proj".  Is that the PROJ library?  It seems like Ubuntu's got PROJ=6.3.1 while the reply was from PROJ=7.2.1. And that the 7.2.1 is a Windows release??  Not clear.  Is it possible to replace the PROJ in an installation of PostGIS?  (ChatGPT says this is not recommended...  for what that's worth.)